# ping not working on some domains

Tags: ping, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to get my head around an issue I'm facing. I can ping most sites:

```
ping -v google.com
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
PING google.com(lhr48s28-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4009:821::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from lhr48s28-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4009:821::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=1.52 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s28-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4009:821::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=121 time=1.54 ms
^X^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.522/1.531/1.540/0.009 ms
```

But so far my tests have found 3 out of thousands of domains, that just refuse to ping.

```
ping -v comset.net
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
```

It just hangs and hangs.

Weirdly, if I do it off another one of my servers (same software, setup etc), it works:

```
ping -v comset.net
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
PING comset.net (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
^X^C
--- comset.net ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.021/0.041/0.061/0.020 ms
```

How can I debug what is causing this?

**UPDATE:** As requested, here is a result from `dig`:

```
dig comset.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> comset.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48627
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 106, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;comset.net.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.81
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.16
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.105
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.135
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.136
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.165
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.167
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.150
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.156
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.17
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.159
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.3
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.107
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.15
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.51
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.23
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.112
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.146
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.14
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.130
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       217.195.65.20
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.147
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.134
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.8
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.148
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.6
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.21
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.138
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.1
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.122
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.124
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.133
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.163
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.168
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.18
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.158
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.104
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.153
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.11
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.145
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.166
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.26
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.129
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.24
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.106
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.131
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.19
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.5
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.157
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.123
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.103
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.31
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.9
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.116
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.149
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.28
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.30
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.139
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.144
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.7
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.169
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.114
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.121
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.152
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.20
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.126
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.29
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.118
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.71
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.125
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.4
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.127
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.41
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.155
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.162
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.115
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.143
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.113
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.27
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.25
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.142
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.132
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.102
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.12
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.117
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.2
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.101
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.100
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.137
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.140
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.141
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.160
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.110
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.109
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.10
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.61
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.111
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.154
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.128
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.164
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.13
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.108
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.119
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.161
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.22
comset.net.             1800    IN      A       127.0.0.91

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 14 13:06:58 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1735
```

Comment: Run `dig comset.net`. Seems a bit odd...

Comment: @Paul - tell me about it :) I've updated my question with the dig results for that domain. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if that is permitted per RFC, only I'm not sure which one covers A records.

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: @Paul, sorry, that went right over my head =)

Comment: @Bert- WSL? This is Ubuntu 18.04 on Linode

Comment: I'm imagining there is an RFC somewhere stating what is supposed to be in a public A record, and perhaps certain IP addresses or blocks are not supposed to be there.

Comment: @Paul ah ok. Surely it wouldn't work on both servers if that's the case? (both are on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: I am referring to the IETF "Request for Comment" documents found at https://www.ietf.org/standards/rfcs/, which are rules admins and others are expected to follow. However, software can always be written or configured to violate these rules.

Comment: @Paul right. I know I haven't changed anything around it :) (I wouldn't know where to even start!)

Comment: The aspect I was wondering about is for the admins of `comset.net` placing 127.x.x.x in A records, not so much anything in regards to your configuration. Also, just idle curiosity on my part, not really going to answer your question.

Comment: @Paul haha. Its really really weird. Even with a timeout it doesn't fail: `ping -W 5 -v comset.net`. Interestingly, I just found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069381/why-ping-timeout-is-not-working-correctly . I wonder if it is indeed around `getaddrinfo` not accepting a timeout (and not ignoring it!). Interestingly I can force it to die with: `timeout 3 ping foo.com` (and it dies if no response after 3 secs)